# Grouping the data based on the time of occurrence of an event

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Here's my current dataset:

```
Id                                      Province    Time
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    ON          2013-09-04 16:38:06.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    ON          2013-09-05 07:58:08.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    ON          2013-09-05 10:43:07.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    QC          2013-09-05 10:44:07.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    QC          2013-09-05 10:45:07.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    QC          2013-09-05 11:12:07.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    QC          2013-09-05 11:58:08.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    ON          2013-09-05 12:00:08.000
```

Above data is stored in a CTE and following is the query:

```
;With CTE
AS
(
Select S.Id, S.Province, MIN(S.LocalTimeStamp) As MinTime From Table S 
    Where [Description] = 'Test Desc'
    Group By Id, Province, Zone
)   

Select * From CTE
    Order By CTE.MinTime
```

Expected result:

```
Id                                      Province    Time
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    ON          2013-09-04 16:38:06.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    QC          2013-09-05 10:44:07.000
18D066A7-4FFB-462A-A203-DF468F814A43    ON          2013-09-05 12:00:08.000
```

The scenario is: a vehicle starts from ON goes to QC and returns ON.

I want separate rows for the start and return within the province on ON. it works fine when **TIME** falls on different dates as I can group by Date part of the **TIME**. But the problem is when all three are on same day.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

What if you compare the time difference between the initial date and the following dates?  Something like this:

```
-- First, get the initial date:
;WITH CTE1
AS
(Select Id, MIN(S.LocalTimeStamp) As MinTime From Table S 
    Where [Description] = 'Test Desc' AND Province = 'ON'
    Group By Id 

, CTE2
AS
(
Select S.Id, S.Province, MIN(DATEDIFF(ms, CTE1.MinTime, S.LocalTimeStamp)) As MinTime, S.LocalTimeStamp
From Table S
    INNER JOIN CTE1
        ON Table.ID = CTE1.ID 
Where [Description] = 'Test Desc'
Group By Id, Province, Zone
)   

Select * From CTE2
    Order By CTE.MinTime
```